# Surface Pro 1 with Ubuntu 15.04 Problem; You need to load the kernel first

Tags: kernel

I've installed Ubuntu successfully then told me to reboot, but I'm stuck in the screen where I had to choose four options: 
1) Try Ubuntu without installing
2) Install Ubuntu
3) OEM Install
4) Check disks for defects
So I press 'c' then type in boot then it tells me "you need to load kernel first.
Help appreciated, thank you!